# Backbone/Parse app: links don't work on first load

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform, single-page-application

I'm creating a single-page web app using the Parse JS library, which is an extension of Backbone.

My Router is set up as follows:

```
var AppRouter = Parse.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "signup",
      "signup": "signup",
      "login": "login",
      "logout": "logout",
      "dashboard": "dashboard",
      "history": "history",
      "account": "account"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
    },

    login: function() {
      this.navigateTo(new LoginView(), false);
    },

    logout: function() {
      Parse.User.logOut();
      Parse.history.navigate("signup", true);
    },

    signup: function() {
      this.navigateTo(new SignupView(), false);
    },

    dashboard: function() {
      this.navigateTo(new DashboardView(), true);
    },

    history: function () {
      this.navigateTo(new SentMailView(), true);
    },

    account: function () {
      this.navigateTo(new AccountView(), true);
    },

    navigateTo: function(view, needsSignedIn) {
      if (needsSignedIn && !Parse.User.current()) {
        Parse.history.navigate("signup", true);
      } else if (!needsSignedIn && Parse.User.current()) {
        Parse.history.navigate("dashboard", true);
      } else {
        this.loadView(view);
      }
    },

    loadView: function(view) {
      this.view && (this.view.close ? this.view.close() : delete this);
      this.view = view;
    }
  });
```

At the end of my `main.js`, I'm creating a new Router, View, and setting `pushState` to true:

```
new AppRouter;
new AppView;
Parse.history.start({pushState: true});
```

The problem I'm having is that occasionally (often when I first load a page of the app), none of the links work, and all they do is refresh the page. For instance, clicking on a link to '/history' does not load the history page, it just reloads the current page. Similarly, clicking a link to a bootstrap dropdown menu, which is just supposed to trigger a js call, will also reload the current page. Refreshing the browser (via the refresh button) usually fixes this, and then all the links work fine.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The issue was being caused by an underlying view that wasn't being properly deleted. This view had a function that was being bound to the "click a" event -- a click on any  element. The same function was being bound to click events on all links in the dashboard view, which I did not want.